# How can I better control this jQuery UI script, which adds an overlay to a div on a mouseover/mouseout event?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm building a homepage for a website, which features a lot of promotional links contained within `<div>` elements.

To make it more interesting I've designed an overlay `<img>`, which I'd like to appear over the `<div>` when the user hovers their cursor over the corresponding promo, and then disappear when the cursor is removed. I'm animating it on and off using the jQuery UI `.toggle()` effect, like this:

```
$("#hp-promo-1").on("mouseover", function() {
  $("#promo-1-overlay").toggle("slide", {direction: "right"})
})

$("#hp-promo-1").on("mouseout", function() {
  $("#promo-1-overlay").toggle("slide", {direction: "right"})
})
```

Although this *does* work, insofar as it animates the overlay on and off, I'm having problems exercising any sort of control over it. Sometimes the overlay will just slide on and off repeatedly, even after a `mouseout` event.

What could I introduce to this code to ensure that the overlay slides on once and then remains where it is on `mouseover`, and then slides off once and stays hidden on `mouseout?`

Comment: can you create a fiddle link here so we can recreate your problem? Most likely you are triggering the mouseover/-out events multiple times (because of your html-css, not caused by your JS)

Comment: Yes - this seems to be the problem. I'll put a fiddle together when I get a second, but the problem seems to be caused when I move the mouse over - for example - text in the div, which is obviously a different element and causes an unexpected ```mouseout``` event.

Answer (score 0):

I solved this by substituting `mouseover` and `mouseout` with `mouseenter` and `mouseleave`.

The problem was being caused by the cursor passing over elements contained within the `<div>` (eg text), which was triggering the `mouseout` event, but `mouseleave` ignores elements contained within the `<div>`, and only fires when the user's cursor has left the div itself.